# How do I read a downloades sql query on pandas

Tags: python, sql, database, pandas, dataset

I should explore a downloaded dataset, I cant't have the sql credential, I'm using jupyter lab, and the sql file is on same folder with the jupyter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_sql_table('DATA_SPPT.sql')
```

The error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-4a4c42554a20> in <module>()
----> 1 pd.read_sql_table('DATA_SPPT_OP_BERSAMA.sql')

TypeError: read_sql_table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'con'
```

This is download in sql format, so I guess I don't need to describe connection, so what should I do?

Comment: You mean it is a `sql` query? If it is, you are using `read_sql_table` wrongly, you **need** to declare the connection you are querying the table. If not try reading your file as a text file.

Comment: using `read_sql`,`read_sql_table` are `read_sql_query` is give same error

Comment: I mean you are trying to return the query itself and not the dataset rite?

Comment: I'm not sure about what you mean, the file is on `.sql` format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the `read_sql` methods of `pandas`. `pandas` does not have a specific method to read `.sql` files though it provides methods for connections with SQL type servers support by SQLAlchemy.

If you would like to return the contents of your `.sql` file, you can read then file by using Python's context manager where it returns a list of every line and filtering out empty lines with a list comprehension:

```
with open('DATA_SPPT.sql','r') as f:
    lines = [line.strip() for line in f if line.strip()]
```

And if for whatever reason you really need to return a dataframe from it:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
```

If you want to pass the `.sql` file directly from `pandas`, **but you need to declare your `con` string to the database:**

```
with open('DATA_SPPT.sql','r') as f:
    df = pd.read_sql_query(f, con)
```